Docker file run error 'can't create directory '/pyenv/': Permission denied'
I have created below docker file. While running the image it gives out error. Not able to find the route cause of it.
First I build the images from below docker file. then after that I used same image to run the docker using command as 'docker run jspusr/initConfiguration'. After running there are multiple errors and one of the error is permission denied for creating directory.
I have used root user at the start of the docker file so that it should not have permission issue, but still error occours. Also one more error is 'sh: true: unknown operand'
Dockwefile is as below:
FROM dmp/deployApp:6.0.0.0.0 AS builder1

USER root

COPY ./build-python-package.sh /dmp/build-python-package.sh

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/
ENV PYENV_ROOT="/prereqs/pyenv"
ENV PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
ENV PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared"

RUN yum install -y gcc-7.3.1 zlib-devel-1.2.7 bzip2-1.0.6 bzip2-devel-1.0.6 readline-devel-6.2 sqlite-3.7.17 sqlite-devel-3.7.17 tk-devel-8.5.13 libffi-devel-3.0.13 xz-5.2.2 dos2unix-6.0.3 expat-devel-2.1.0 gcc-c++-7.3.1-15.amzn2.x86_64 gdbm-devel-1.13 ncurses-devel-6.0 tcl-devel-8.5.13 yum-utils-1.1.31 xz-devel-5.2.2 findutils-4.5.11 make-3.82 patch-2.7.1 blas-3.4.2 blas-devel-3.4.2 lapack-3.4.2 lapack-devel-3.4.2; \
    yum install -y openssl11-1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.9.x86_64 openssl11-devel-1.1.1g-12.amzn2.0.9.x86_64; \
    yum install -y java-11-amazon-corretto-11.0.18+10; \
    yum install -y wget-1.14-18.amzn2.1.x86_64; \
    yum install -y tar-1.26; \
    yum clean all; \
    mkdir /tools; \
    wget https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/archive/refs/tags/v2.3.8.tar.gz -q -P /tools/; \
    mkdir -p /prereqs/pyenv; \
    tar -xvf /tools/v2.3.8.tar.gz --directory /prereqs/pyenv --strip 1; \
    pyenv init -; \

    # Add the versions of python required here
    pyenv install -v 3.6.13; \
    pyenv install -v 3.10.0; \

    # Add the versions of numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, dill, joblib and jep that are required for all tenants in the root level of a given Python version here
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip; \
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/bin/python -m pip install numpy==1.19.5 scipy==1.5.4 scikit-learn==0.24.2 dill==0.3.4 joblib==1.1.1 jep==4.1.1; \

    # Add the tenant specific libraries and their installation locations here for a given version of Python
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/bin/python -m pip install -t /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/tenant-packages/Base Tenant/v1 numpy==1.19.5 pandas==1.1.5; \
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/bin/python -m pip install -t /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/tenant-packages/T1/v1 numpy==1.19.5 scipy==1.5.4 dill==0.3.4 scikit-learn==0.24.2 joblib==1.1.1 pandas==1.1.5 py==1.11.0; \
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/bin/python -m pip install -t /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.6.13/tenant-packages/T2/v1 scipy==1.5.4 dill==0.3.4 scikit-learn==0.24.2 joblib==1.1.1; \

    # Add the versions of numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, dill, joblib and jep that are required for all tenants in the root level of a specific Python version here
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip; \
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python -m pip install numpy==1.24.2 scipy==1.10.0 scikit-learn==1.2.1 dill==0.3.6 joblib==1.2.0 jep==4.1.1; \

    # Add the tenant specific libraries and their installation locations here for a given version of Python
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python -m pip install -t '/prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/tenant-packages/Base Tenant/v1' numpy==1.24.2 pandas==1.1.5; \
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python -m pip install -t /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/tenant-packages/T1/v1 numpy==1.24.2 scipy==1.10.0 dill==0.3.6 scikit-learn==1.2.2 joblib==1.2.0 pandas==2.0.1 py==1.11.0; \
    /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/bin/python -m pip install -t /prereqs/pyenv/versions/3.10.0/tenant-packages/T2/v1 scipy==1.5.4 dill==0.3.4 scikit-learn==0.24.2 joblib==1.1.1; \

    chmod u+x /dmp/build-python-package.sh; \
    /dmp/build-python-package.sh;

    

USER root

COPY --from=builder1 /prereqs/pyenv/versions /temp/pyenv/versions
COPY ./setup.sh /setup/setup.sh

RUN mkdir -p /prereqs; \
    chown dmp:dmp /setup/setup.sh; \
    chmod u+x /setup/setup.sh; \
    chown -R dmp:dmp /prereqs/;

ADD  ./xpress/*.tar.gz /xpress/

USER dmp
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/setup/setup.sh"]

I tried to run this docker file but not able to find the exact resolution for the error.

Can you please show the exact errors? In particular, what exactly is the first command that fails?
